# How to Process Versioned Objects in Event Handlers and Callbacks

Tags: java, c#, json, serialization

**My Question**:
Is there a best known method for processing different versions of objects that have been deserialized in handlers or callbacks?

**Some Background Info**:
We are going to be using serialized objects as messages to communicate between various components in a software suite.  These could be in JSON form or using something like [protobufs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).  Anytime you start to serialize objects, either for long term storage or between different versions of an application, you have to be able to handle different versions of those objects (maybe using Annotations-Java or Attributes-C#).
I'm trying to avoid code like this:

```
onRecvMyMsg(MyMsg msg)
{
  if (msg.version == 1.0)
    // process it here
  else if (msg.version < 1.5)
    // process it here 
  else if (msg.version < 2.0)
    // process part of it in the 1.5 handler and the other part here
  else if // etc...
}
```

It seems like this would be a maintenance nightmare after many additions/enhancements/changes...
Surely, someone must have been solved this since this seems like a very common practice in software engineering. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my original approach is that the solution is oriented towards the wrong direction.  We are thinking that the processing entity, or consumer of the object, is required to know versions so it can properly handle the differences between them.  **What we could be thinking about, instead, is how we can get the object to express itself based on the version of the processor (or consumer)**.

If we use a serialization technology like [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/), or [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) we are half way there in obtaining what we want.  Libraries like these handle versioning for us, in a sense.  Generally speaking they behave like this:

- if a field is received but not defined it is simply dropped
- if a field is defined but not received, a flag indicates that it is
  not present and an optional default value can be supplied

These libraries also support "required" fields; however, most people (including the authors) don't recommend using "required" fields on the protocol objects themselves because a "required" field will break comparability for all time, both ways (send and receive) if there is a "required" field not present.  They suggest handling required fields on the processing side.

Since the libraries mentioned handle all of the work required to serialize and deserialize objects in a backward and forward compatible manner, all we really need to do is wrap those protocol objects into something else that can expose the data in the form that the consumer expects.
For example, here are 3 versions of the same message that can be processed.

```
ReviewCommentMsg // VERSION 1
{
 string : username
 string : comment
} 

ReviewCommentMsg  // VERSION 2 (added "isLiked")
{
 string : username
 string : comment
 bool   : isLiked
} 

ReviewCommentMsg  // VERSION 3 (added "location", removed "isLiked")
{
 string : username
 string : comment
 string : location
}
```

The following demonstrates how we could incrementally update the client code to process those messages.

```
/*******************************************************************************
  EXAMPLE OBJECT V1
*******************************************************************************/
class ReviewComment
{
  private final String username;
  private final String comment;

  ReviewComment(ReviewCommentMessage msg)
  {
    // Throws exception if fields are not present.
    requires(msg.hasUsername());
    requires(msg.hasComment());

    this.username = msg.getUsername();
    this.comment = msg.getComment();
  }

  String getUsername() { return this.username; }

  String getComment()  { return this.comment; }
}

/*******************************************************************************
  EXAMPLE PROCESSOR V1
*******************************************************************************/
public void processReviewComment(ReviewComment review)
{
  // Simulate posting the review to the blog.
  BlogPost.log(review.getUsername(), review.getComment());
}


/*******************************************************************************
  EXAMPLE OBJECT V2
*******************************************************************************/
class ReviewComment
{
  private final String username;
  private final String comment;
  private final Boolean isLiked;

  ReviewComment(ReviewCommentMessage msg)
  {
    // Throws exception if fields are not present.
    requires(msg.hasUsername());
    requires(msg.hasComment());

    this.username = msg.getUsername();
    this.comment = msg.getComment();

    if (msg.hasIsLiked())
    {
      this.isLiked = msg.getIsLiked();
    }
  }

  String getUsername() { return this.username; }

  String getComment()  { return this.comment; }

  // Use Java's built in "Optional" class to indicate that this field is optional.
  Optional<Boolean> isLiked() { return Optional.of(this.isLiked); }
}

/*******************************************************************************
  EXAMPLE PROCESSOR V2
*******************************************************************************/
public void processReviewComment(ReviewComment review)
{
  // Simulate posting the review to the blog.
  BlogPost.log(review.getUsername(), review.getComment());

  Optional<Boolean> isLiked = review.isLiked();

  if (isLiked.isPresent() && !isLiked.get())
  {
    // If the field is present AND is false, send an email telling us someone
    // did not like the product.
    Stats.sendEmailBadReview(review.getComment());  
  }
}


/*******************************************************************************
  EXAMPLE OBJECT V3
*******************************************************************************/
class ReviewComment
{
  private final String username;
  private final String comment;
  private final String location;

  ReviewComment(ReviewCommentMessage msg)
  {
    // Throws exception if fields are not present.
    requires(msg.hasUsername());
    requires(msg.hasComment());
    requires(msg.hasLocation());

    this.username = msg.getUsername();
    this.comment = msg.getComment();
    this.location = msg.getLocation();
  }

  String getUsername() { return this.username; }

  String getComment()  { return this.comment; }

  String getLocation()  { return this.location; }
}

/*******************************************************************************
  EXAMPLE PROCESSOR V3
*******************************************************************************/
public void processReviewComment(ReviewComment review)
{
  // Simulate posting the review to the blog.
  BlogPost.log(review.getUsername(), review.getComment());

  // Simulate converting the location into geo coordinates.
  GeoLocation geoLocation = GeoLocation.from(review.getLocation());

  // Simulate posting the location to the blog.
  BlogPost.log(review.getUsername(), geoLocation);
}
```

**In this example:**
*PROCESSOR V1* can receive messages *(V1, V2, and V3)*
*PROCESSOR V2* can receive messages *(V1, V2, and V3)*
*PROCESSOR V3* can receive messages *(V3)*

This approach puts the compatibility concern in the message objects themselves and alleviates clients/processors from having a bunch of version checking.
**Admittedly, you still have to perform some semantic checking; however, that seems far less cumbersome than building in version logic to every client.**

Comment: I'll leave my answer up for a little while before accepting it to see if someone else has a better approach. I'm interested to see if there are other ideas about this.